# ServiceForbidden Exception while adding entry to google calendar

Tags: calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-client, android-calendar

I am trying to add an entry in google calendar but getting service forbidden exception. It's a simple entry having a title, content and a date range. Code snippet provided below;

```
public void temp() {
URL postURL = null;
try {
    postURL = new URL("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/MAILID@gmail.com/PASSWORD/full");
    EventEntry eventEntry = new EventEntry();
    eventEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("One"));
    eventEntry.setContent(new PlainTextConstruct("Two"));

    When eventTime = new When();
    eventTime.setStartTime(DateTime.parseDateTime("2016-03-09T15:00:00-08:00"));
    eventTime.setEndTime(DateTime.parseDateTime("2016-03-09T15:00:00-08:00"));
    eventEntry.addTime(eventTime);

    CalendarService calendarService = new CalendarService("Savor");
    EventEntry createdEvent = calendarService.insert(postURL, eventEntry);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

While doing this, I am getting ServiceForbidden exception provided below[Please ignore the line numbers shown in exception]

```
    com.google.gdata.util.ServiceForbiddenException: Forbidden
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Forbidden</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Forbidden</H1>
<H2>Error 403</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>

    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:605)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.insert(Service.java:1409)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.insert(GoogleService.java:613)
    at GCalender.temp(GCalender.java:68)
    at GCalender.main(GCalender.java:85)
```

Exception occurs in this line: EventEntry createdEvent = calendarService.insert(postURL, eventEntry);

Trying to resolve this but sort of stucked up at this point. If anyone has came across this already, please provide your inputs, would be a great help..

Thanks!!

PS: Pls. ignore if the question is tagged with incorrect tag entries.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Google Calendar API v2 which is [Shut down.](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory)  You need to switch to [Google Calendar v3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/)

Documentation for [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#parameters)

```
event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
```

**Update:**

Your code has the following

```
MAILID@gmail.com/PASSWORD/
```

You need to also be aware that accessing Google APIs using a login and password no longer works.  Client login was also shut down.  You will need to Authenticate your application using Oauth2.

Comment: And before you ask or go off and try and get it to work? Could not understand this??

Comment: MAILID@gmail.com/PASSWORD/  <--- that makes me think that you think you can get access using the users login and password.  You cant. You need to use Oauth2 to access Google Calendar.

Comment: Thanks for the response!!!! Thats crct, Naive questions: I am very new to oauth/oauth2. Hv gone through the link and I have to generate a JSON for every new user gmail ID on which I need to mark calender entry?

Comment: I will design a simple user interface in my app to get the mail ID/pwd. 
But how to generate the JSON which is further required for this process?!                         Can you provide some more idea on this pls., if possible??!?. I am eating up too much of your time :-(